# An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (738369013) when submitting to Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to update my app, I have successfully uploaded the apk package, I got this error when I clicked the VIEW button.

Comment: You know this question has already been asked – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357276/an-unexpected-error-occurred-please-try-again-later-738369013-when-submittin – as you posted a non-answer there asking if it's been solved. Rather than posting the same question again, you should just keep an eye on that one.

Comment: We encountered the same error, but the way we generated the error was different